# USB флешка с FAT32 + EXTfs под Linux-ом

Tags: linux, ext4, fat32, flash-память

Хотелось-бы сделать странную флешку: чтобы на ней был *ext[234]* и *FAT32* одновременно.

Но не с двумя разделами, а с одним разделом, то есть, сделать что-то типа (`/dev/sdf` — это флешка):

1. Создаем файл `badblocks`, в нем указываем блоки, идущие подряд, а суммарный объем этих *bad*-блоков совпадает с разделом *FAT32*.
2. Форматируем флешку целиком в *ext[234]* с указанием файла `badblocks` (`mkfs.ext4 -b badblocks /dev/sdf`).
3. Через *fdisk* (`fdisk /dev/sdf`) создаем единственный *primary*-раздел, который находится в области, отмеченной в `badblocks`.
4. Форматируем `/dev/sdf1` в *FAT32*

Понятно, что в *linux*-е мне такой флешку придется монтировать руками, зато под виндою она подхватится автоматически.

Возможно, существует какой-нибудь *HOWTO* на эту тему, просто с первой попытки не нашел.

Answer (score 3):

для того, чтобы операционная система *ms/windows* могла примонтировать раздел со своей «родной» файловой системой *fat*, вовсе не требуется тех ухищрений, что изложены в вопросе.

необходимо и достаточно, чтобы этот раздел был **первым** на *usb-storage* (aka «флэшка»), у которой установлен *removable bit*.

все остальные разделы, какая бы там ни была файловая система, для *ms/windows* (без каких-нибудь специализированных средств) остаются «вне поля зрения» — воспринимается **только** первый раздел.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы невнимательно прочли вопрос.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, я думаю, что **конечную цель** автора уловил верно.

Comment: Нет, он написал именно то, что он хотел сделать — возможно стебу ради — как бы, тайный носитель в явном носителе. Если бы он хотел сделать просто два логических раздела, он точно вопроса не задавал.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, для подавляющего большинства пользователей сам факт существования второго раздела извлекаемого блочного устройства будет тайной. обсуждать же, кто и что имел ввиду **на самом деле**, мне неинтересно.

Comment: Нет, винда будет показывать второй раздел как неразмеченное пространство *(где-то в дисковых утилитах)*. Нахрена отвечать вопрос, если даже «**не интересно что автор имел ввиду**»©?

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что речь об [этом приёме](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/hide-data-in-bad-blocks/). Способ заключается в переключении между двумя таблицами разделов, в каждой из которых по одному разделу. В одной из них раздел при создании файловой системы получил на вход крупную последовательность "битых блоков", обходящую местонахождение раздела из второй таблицы.

На флэшке виден в каждый момент только **один** из этих двух, переключение происходит посредством... перезаписи таблицы разделов.

> [image: Схема диска]

Предполагается, что в обычном состоянии флэшка содержит таблицу разделов, с которой видна только файловая система с "зелёным" пространством. Когда "тихо и спокойно", можно записать на флэшку другую таблицу разделов (pro tip: её можно хранить в последнем секторе диска, только надо его обходить остальными инструментами) и тем самым получить доступ к "секретному разделу", потеряв доступ к основному. "Сделав дело", можно вернуть исходную таблицу разделов обратно, вернув флэшку в обычное состояние.

Какие файловые системы будут на внешнем и внутреннем разделах, совершенно неважно (лишь бы файловая система умела обходить стороной "плохие" блоки). Windows вполне может видеть оба раздела при условии перезаписи таблицы разделов (и осознании этого факта операционной системой) и совместимой файловой системы на них (например, FAT32). То есть, если вы забудете вернуть исходную таблицу разделов на место, **Windows** в этом случае **успешно увидит секретный раздел.**

**Такой раздел не стоит делать большим**, потому что "плохие блоки" в рамках файловой системы обычно числятся как **"всегда занятые"** во всяких графических инструментах. Так что если диск пуст (нет файлов и папок, в т. ч. скрытых), а на нём занято существенное количество места (заметно больше, чем на диске всего "сырого места" минус структуры ФС), то это может быть сигналом того, что на диске имеется подобная штука.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post1116413.html) есть довольно-таки старая, но весёлая инструкция. Или не то?

Comment: Нет, там не совсем то, что нужно - там просто как создать правильный partition table на флешке

Comment: А для чего это нужно? Раздел внутри раздела? Ну, на то extended partition есть, в которой можно сделать сколько надо разнотипных логических. Раздел в файл упрятать? Такое тоже есть, но судя из вопроса, оба раздела должны быть видны. Непонятно...